# Making rdlc datasource filter from other datasource

Tags: rdlc, localreport

So to summarise the problem, I have a report which has two datasources - and is really two reports stuck to each other. I want the second part of the report to display data based on what the first part of the report is showing.

To go into more detail, the situation is as follows. I have two database tables - lets call one Customers, and the other Orders.

Customers contains data about the customers.
Orders contains a link to customers and contains the person's orders.

The report itself is supposed to display some sort of letter in part 1:

"Hello [CustomerName], you have an ongoing balance of [TotalBalance] bla bla bla..."
and a list of all the orders he has made in part 2
"Order 1: Item 1: 1 euro
Order 2: Item 2: 2 euro ..."

Originally these were two separate reports which we were generating one record at a time, outputting as pdf files and merging them using third party software such that the letter and the list of orders were next to each other. The problem is that this system will need to generate hundreds of them at a time, and it was taking ages. So now I want to pass a pair of large data sources and generate them in batches (call them 600 at a time) - which works faster.

So how can I force the second tablix which uses a different datasource, to filter based on what is in the first tablix with its own datasource?

I've looked at subreports, but they only work using reporting server and these are local reports.

Anything I can do ? I'm worried that its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason subreports won't work with local reports.

I recommend you download the samples from this site [ReportViewer Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/reportviewer). The project named "SupplyingData" shows how to load data into a subreport.

Comment: Well I tried putting the subreport in. It gave a localreportexception which stated that subreports require a reporting server. I'm using the webforms dll, if that makes a difference.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference if you use Webforms.  Download the "ASP.NET samples" and check out the "SupplyingData" project. It has what you need.  The key, by the way, to use subreports is to load their data in the ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing eventhandler.